# How to copy current timestamp to clipboard in MPC BE?

Tags: video, autohotkey, video-playback, media-player-classic

I have visited every link on the internet but cannot seem to find a solution.

What I want to do is that copy the current timestamp of the video I am watching and then paste it into the Word Document that I am writing. I basically make notes of the scenes, so that I am later able to go back to that particular scene in the video.

Answer (score 2):

My version of Media Player Classic (MPC) is different than yours,
but may be similar enough for this to work.

The way I found to get the timestamp is to enter the following
key sequences in order :

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> : Go to timestamp dialog displays
  the current timestamp, the cursor is inside the timestamp field which
  is displaying the current timestamp
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> : Selects the field
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> : Copies the field to the clipboard.

If entering this key sequence gets boring, you may use
the free [AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/)
with the following script to do it with only the <kbd>F10</kbd> key:

```
#IfWinActive ahk_class MediaPlayerClassicW        ; only when MPC is active
F10::
SendMessage, 0x111, 893,,, ahk_class MediaPlayerClassicW   ; same as ctrl-g
Sleep,10                   ; sleep 10 milliseconds
SendInput,^A               ; ctrl-a
Sleep,10
SendInput,^C               ; ctrl-c
Sleep,10
SendInput,{Esc}            ; escape
```

After installing AutoHotKey, put the above text in a `.ahk` file and
double-click it to test. You may stop the script by right-click on
the green H icon in the traybar and choosing Exit. To have it run on login,
place it in the Startup group at
`C:\Users\USER-NAME\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup`.

Useful AutoHotkey documentation:

- [List of Keys](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/KeyList.htm)
- [Hotkeys](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm)

Comment: Hey man! So I just tried your script. I had to replace the Title Name to MPC-BE and SetTitleMatchMode as 2. However the script just goes upto the first step. It presses Ctrl + G but does not perform rest of the steps. Any idea what could be causing that?

Comment: Try to increase the `Sleep` amount, especially on the first one to give the dialog more time to come up.